# October CMS One To One

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have a model for House and one for Reservation.

House has ID, NAME... columns. And Reservation has ID, HOUSE_ID; FULL_NAME.

One reservation have only one house. I create relations:

```html
public $hasOne = [
  'house_id' => ['..\..\Models\House', 'key' => 'id']
];
```

But as soon as I save my record HOUSE_ID is saved NULL.
Do I have to store the ID from the selected house to the reservation table in HOUSE_ID columns?

Comment: With this amount of details your question can not be answered, sorry. Basically yes: Create a foreign key reference from the house_id column to the ID column of house.

Comment: can you share how you are saving your reservation [from backend ?], and if possible its `yaml` file